# ff and rewind without using the currentTime attribute

Tags: javascript, html, video

I'm working on a HTML5 (for HLS videos) video player and i'm having problems to do trickplay actions (ff and rewind). the main issue is that the player doesn't seem to work with the currentTime attribute. is there any other property that i could use, don't know something like seekByTime , or SkippTo .
Any help? 
this is my code (actually not working) :

```
function fastForward(mediaPlayer){
    var a=mediaPlayer.duration;
    var b=mediaPlayer.currentTime;
  if(a>b){
    mediaPlayer.currentTime=mediaPlayer.currentTime+10;
  }
};


function rewind(mediaPlayer){
    var a=mediaPlayer.duration;
    var b=mediaPlayer.currentTime;
   if(b>10){
     mediaPlayer.currentTime=mediaPlayer.currentTime-60;
   }
};
```

Comment: what it happens actually  is that you press ff or rewind , and : the current playing gets paused (not the player it self , i mean the screen gets frozen), the progress bar goes to the correct time jump, waits for a second or two, and then returns to the time where it was playing before the button got pushed

Answer (score 0):

I try changing currentTime on Chrome 36, and IE 11 and run like a charm. In iOS you can also use PlaybackRate with negative values.

The code that I tested:

```
function changeCurrentTime(direction) {
    if (direction == "-" && _video.currentTime > 5)
        _video.currentTime -= 5;
    else if (direction == "+" && _video.currentTime < _video.duration + 5)
        _video.currentTime += 5;
}
```

In http://jsfiddle.net/5v2etjfg/6/ you can find my complete example.

Inspired on: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/Audio_and_video_delivery/HTML5_playbackRate_explained

Hope this help.

Comment: But you are using currentTime to ff o rewind, my question was the oposite, i mean, can you ff or rewind without using currentTime or playbackRate ? is there any other property ?

Comment: It seems that not much more than that. In [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp) you can find more info about the attributes and events of VIDEO tag.